# windows authentication iis 10 with asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a .NET 6 application (asp mvc) running under IIS 10 on Windows 2016 server and cannot get integrated windows authentication working properly as I continue to get prompted for a login. I have set Windows Authentication to enabled in IIS with all other security types disabled and my application web.config file authentication/authorization is set up as:

```
***<system.web>
<authenticationmode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
<deny users = "?" />
</authorization>
</system.web>***
```

With this setup, I'm expecting behind the scene verification of the Windows user to allow access and deny anonymous users. However, what I'm getting is a Windows login pop-up when I try to access the site.

I really appreciate any help anyone can provide so that I'm still using only windows authentication but don't get the pop-up and the windows authentication is performed against the actual Windows user.

Comment: IIS/ASP.NET side settings won't stop the prompt, as that's a browser side setting. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password and the browser's documentation for resolution please.

Comment: you could try to use iis authentication and set disable anonymous authentication and enable windows authentication. or another option is you could set authentication rule to allow some users so it will only allow specified users.